# DataTorrent: JDBC operator not working

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, hadoop, jdbc, apache-apex

I am replacing the console operator in WordCountDemo but it is giving me a operatorError in STRAM Events. When I click on it it shows me nullpointer error. I am very new to datatorrent.

Here is the complete error message:

```
Abandoning deployment due to setup failure. java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at com.datatorrent.lib.db.jdbc.JdbcStore.connect(JdbcStore.java:163)
    at com.datatorrent.lib.db.jdbc.JdbcTransactionalStore.connect(JdbcTransactionalStore.java:118)
    at com.datatorrent.lib.db.AbstractTransactionableStoreOutputOperator.setup(AbstractTransactionableStoreOutputOperator.java:94)
    at com.datatorrent.lib.db.jdbc.AbstractJdbcTransactionableOutputOperator.setup(AbstractJdbcTransactionableOutputOperator.java:81)
    at com.datatorrent.lib.db.jdbc.AbstractJdbcTransactionableOutputOperator.setup(AbstractJdbcTransactionableOutputOperator.java:58)
    at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.Node.setup(Node.java:182)
    at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer.setupNode(StreamingContainer.java:1290)
    at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer.access$100(StreamingContainer.java:129)
    at com.datatorrent.stram.engine.StreamingContainer$2.run(StreamingContainer.java:1369)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't set the properties that is needed by jdbc operator. You need to set driver/databaseurl/username/password

Here is an example 
dt.operator."your operator name".store.databaseDriver=jdbc.mysql
dt.operator."your operator name".store.databaseUrl=....